# How in Django admin create Groups with permissions for models programmatically?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I want to create two groups "Driver" and "Administrator".
Each group should be have deference permissions for models.

> "**Administrator**" able to add, delete and view certain models.
>
> "**Driver**" able to just add and view certain models.

What is the best approach to make this done?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the action in your project that leads to create these groups. I can guess, you want to create these groups once when you deploy your project without the need to enter the admin panel and create the groups manually. If so, I would recommend you to try `RunPython` migration for it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython

Also you will need to work with the model `Group`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/

A quick example of the migration would look like this:

```
from django.db import migrations


def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("django.contrib.auth", "Group")
    # Create the groups you need here...


def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("django.contrib.auth", "Group")
    # Delete the groups you need here...


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

Creating a new empty migration is available by the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp --empty
```